# How do I make my QTableWidget class (any class) update/refresh itself?

Tags: python, sqlite, class, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am making a gui using pyqt4. When I insert data from sqlite into my qtablewidget table, it will only update itself once I have closed the program and reopened it. How can I have the program update itself automatically (refresh the class) after inserting/deleting or changing the data in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not sure how you are implementing your code, maybe the following code helps you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QTableWidget,QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        """

        super(MyMainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWidgets()

    def setWidgets(self, ):


        vBox = QVBoxLayout()
        mainFrame = QWidget()

        self._pressButton = QPushButton("Update Table",self)
        self._pressButton.clicked.connect(self.updateTable)

        self._table = QTableWidget(self)
        self._table.setRowCount(3)
        self._table.setColumnCount(3)
        vBox.addWidget(self._pressButton)
        vBox.addWidget(self._table)

        mainFrame.setLayout(vBox)
        self.setCentralWidget(mainFrame)

    def updateTable(self, ):

        i = self._table.currentRow()
        if i == -1:
            i=0

        self._table.insertRow(i)
        self._table.setItem(i,0,QTableWidgetItem("Test"))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MyMainWindow()

    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however I just want the class to restart, such as connecting 'MyMainWindow' outside itself (within an other class) to a button etc. to run it again so the table refreshes itself to changes I have made.